# autochange page index in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, page-index-changed

i have one wallboard application in which i have to display some record in a gridview. as number of records are large in numbers so i have to implement paging in gridview. but as it is wallboard application user cannot change the page. so after each 10 seconds i have to show the next page.

**CS file**

```
protected void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GV_ExtCallSummary.PageCount == GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex)
    {
    //    timer1.Enabled = false;
    //    GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex = 1;

    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            //  GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex++;
            GV_ExtCallSummary.SetPageIndex(1);
            //  GV_ExtCallSummary.DataSource = dt;
            GV_ExtCallSummary.DataBind(); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string exv = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

above is the code which i tried with ticker.

if i try to use `GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex++` nothing happens. just increase in `pageindex`.

and if i use `setpageindex(1)` it throws exception that is:

> The GridView 'GV_ExtCallSummary' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled.

even thought the function do exist.

```
protected void GV_ExtCallSummary_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GV_ExtCallSummary.DataSource = dt;
    GV_ExtCallSummary.DataBind();
}
```

and this function works fine if i click on page numbers.

**HTML**
if any one wants to see html code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_ExtCallSummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
Width="100%" Visible="true" OnRowDataBound="GV_ExtCallSummary_RowDataBound"  OnPageIndexChanging="GV_ExtCallSummary_PageIndexChanging"
EmptyDataText="No data exist." AllowPaging="True" CssClass="table" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#669999" 
AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="success" PageSize="10">
<Columns> 
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Extention">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblExt" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Extension") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblExtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExtnName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Abandon">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAdandon" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Abandon") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Incoming">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblIncoming" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Incoming") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Outgoing">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblOutgoing" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Outgoing") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Intercom">
        <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Intercom" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Intercom") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#8AC5FF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.Aspx Code:**

Put your `GridView` inside `ContentTemplate` of the `UpdatePanel`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <!-- Here will be your Gridview Code -->
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<!-- Timer will tick after 10 seconds -->
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

**.CS Code:**

`PageIndex` can be `0` and `PageCount` can be is `1`, so that they can't be equal. Therefore, you have to use this code:

```
protect void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex == (GV_ExtCallSummary.PageCount -1))
    {
        GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex = GV_ExtCallSummary.PageIndex + 1;
    }

    GV_ExtCallSummary.DataSource = dt; // e.g. dt can be your be your data to set
    GV_ExtCallSummary.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou thankyou so much asif. it works for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure that the `PageIndexChanging` event is handled.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    int pageIndex = GridView1.PageIndex + 1;

    //if you want the autmatic page change to stop at the end
    if (pageIndex == GridView1.PageCount)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        return;
    }

    //or loop continuously by going back to the first page
    if (pageIndex == GridView1.PageCount)
    {
        pageIndex = 0;
    }

    //set the new pageindex and rebind the gridview
    GridView1.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = mySource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And in the `Tick`, call the method.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1_PageIndexChanging(null, null);
}
```